# Linux how to launch visible terminal with script file automatically at startup

Tags: linux, terminal, autostart

I have seen many ways to launch a script like putting it in profile.D, rc.local, or creating a auto start file but none of those launch the file in a visible window if at all. I need it to be in a visible window in Ubuntu. I need to do this because I am using several emulators to stream to different services, and I don't want to have to start the script on each manually.

I am using visual box for the emulator. The sh file is on a removable drive because it is an external file. I also need it to run as sudo.

Edit: I don't actually need it to run at startup. I just need to have the script run. I can probably just sleep really long for graphic to load.

Edit 2: So I created a service that launched a sh file in /usr/bin/ which was supposed to create a gnome-terminal window that ran my script. It ran, however It didn't create a visible window for some reason. I then tried to specify a display which caused gnome to freak out. Dbus was not launching correctly. another question stated that gnome would not work because of how it was designed and stated to use konsole instead. Konsole also stated that it could not connect to a display, giving a QXcbConnection error. Konsole does not have an option to specify display. I don't know what else to try

Edit 3: So I did the thing in the comment. And the service works. However it only works after I run the file that the service runs in usr/bin manually after every restart. The important parts of the file:

```
 #!/bin/bash
sleep 60
ufw disable
ssh nateguana@$(hostname) -X
xhost +
*launch Gnome**only works after file ran manually*
```

I have also tried exporting DISPLAY, and changing users with su. I have not tried importing SSHD, as another question said to do, as I think that is only for non local connections. I have also tried every single arrangement of commands possible. Xhost errors stating that it is unable to open display "".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnome-terminal -e <command>` to spawn a new bash terminal which runs the command.

You could use something like

```
gnome-terminal -e /path/to/bashfile
```

Bear in mind, this will end the terminal after the bash scipt is done executing.

To avoid this,in a newline add `$SHELL` to the end of your bash script.

PS: the -e argument is deprecated and might be removed in later versions

Comment: I tried this already. The problem is that the terminal can't be seen. On one of the attempts, While the screen was still black, waiting for the desktop to be visible, there was a terminal that flashed on screen, however it disappeared instantly, and the emulation was also bricked. Never again able to load the desktop, even after restarting several times. This also used the -hold which is keeps the window open. I don't know if that mattered. If Ubuntu was waiting for the window to close, but it never did.

Comment: @Nateguana, Try adding a "$SHELL" to the end of your script. This should keep the terminal open after the script finishes execuion, I'll add the changes to the answer

Comment: How should I start the script though? I have bricked several emulations attempting to get it to start automatically at startup or after login. I think what is happening is that Linux is waiting for the script to stop before it shows the desktop. Again, The problem is not keeping the window open, The problem is that the script itself is holding up the rest of the system. I need a way to get around that.

Comment: @Nateguana, You should consider creating a service to launch your script on startup. This might help https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Comment: `[ ! -z "$DISPLAY" ] && gnome-terminal -e /path/to/bashfile`; put this somewhere in $HOME/.xsessionrc (`man xsession`).